# using awk to exclude a range of rows from one file depeding on second file

Tags: awk

I have two files - file one contains a number (1-22) in column 1 and a range from a lower number (column 2) and upper number (column 3). Here is the first couple of lines:

| 1 | 11362778 | 12362778 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22054176 | 23054176 |
| 1 | 28191734 | 29191734 |
| 1 | 42956767 | 43956767 |
| 1 | 65941329 | 66941329 |

The first file doesnt have any header.

In a second file I have a lot of columns first one shown here:

| SNP | CHR | BP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rs115828134 | 1 | 11363041 |
| rs2788537 | 1 | 11363231 |
| rs12141932 | 1 | 11363301 |

What I want to do is remove all rows in file 2 if column 2 in file 2 is equal to column 1 in file 1 AND if column 3 in file 2 falls within the range of column 2 and column 3 in file 2.

Essentially something like this:, but looping through all the rows of file 1.

```
awk '{if($2==1 && $3 < 11362778 || $3 > 12362778) print $0}' file 2 > results.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree 100% with @jared_mamrot, use proper bioinfo tools for this.

Yet there's a way to approach this with **awk**. But be sure to test this on a real dataset before relying on it for serious science since I am not entirely sure if it covers all corner cases, esp with your limited example.

Data (added matching data):

```
$ cat file1
1       11362778        12362778
1       22054176        23054176
1       28191734        29191734
1       42956767        43956767
1       65941329        66941329
2       42956767        43956767
2       65941329        66941329

$ cat file2
SNP     CHR     BP
rs10875231      1       100000012
rs6678176       1       100000827
rs78286437      1       100000843
rr234233        1       29000000
rr453654        1       29000120
e34534534       1       23444444
rs144406489     1       100001138
rr564564        2       29000120
e34534534       2       23444444
rs144406489     2       42956775
```

Use:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ chr[NR]=$1; x[NR]=$2; y[NR]=$3; en=NR }
       NR!=FNR{ set=0;
                for(i=1;i<=en;i++){
                  if(chr[i]==$2 && ( $3 <= y[i] && $3 >= x[i] ) ){
                    set=0; break
                  }
                  else{ set=1 }
                }
                if(set==1){ print }
      }' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
SNP     CHR     BP
rs10875231      1       100000012
rs6678176       1       100000827
rs78286437      1       100000843
e34534534       1       23444444
rs144406489     1       100001138
rr564564        2       29000120
e34534534       2       23444444
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of domain-specific question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Having said that, one potential solution is to convert the second file into the bed format (same as file 1) then use [bedtools](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to identify and exclude matches.

First, change the first line in file_1 so that the coordinates correspond to an entry in file_2, otherwise you can't see whether the method works:

File_1.bed:

```
1   100000011   100000014
1   22054176    23054176
1   28191734    29191734
1   42956767    43956767
1   65941329    66941329
```

File_2.bed

```
# generated using
# awk 'NR>1 {print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $3 "\t" $1}' file_2 > file_2.bed
1   100000012   100000012   rs10875231
1   100000827   100000827   rs6678176
1   100000843   100000843   rs78286437
1   100001138   100001138   rs144406489
```

Use [bedtools intersect](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) to identify and remove intersecting entries:

```
bedtools intersect -v -a file_2.bed -b file_1.bed
```

Output:

```
1   100000827   100000827   rs6678176
1   100000843   100000843   rs78286437
1   100001138   100001138   rs144406489
```

Comment: Thank you!  Yup- bedtools works, just want to be able to write it as an awk

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work but you don't have testable input so not tested (no overlap in ranges!).

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {c[$1]++; b[$1,c[$1]]=$2; e[$1,c[$1]]=$3; next}
       $2 in c {for(i=1;i<=c[$2];i++) 
                  if(b[$2,i]<$3 && $3<e[$2,i]) next}1' file1 file2
```

also please post the sample input so that it can be copy/pasted for easy testing.

Using the sample inputs from @AndreWildberg's answer and piping to `column` gives

```
$ awk ... | column -t

SNP          CHR  BP
rs10875231   1    100000012
rs6678176    1    100000827
rs78286437   1    100000843
e34534534    1    23444444
rs144406489  1    100001138
rr564564     2    29000120
e34534534    2    23444444
```

Note that this should work slightly faster than the alternative since scanning the overlap is restricted only to matching codes.  Depending on your input size it may be negligible or not.

Comment: Thank you - It looks like it does the oposite of what want - ie it prints all the line I want to remove. I've updated file 2 above

Comment: What I would like is a file omitting the regions of file 1

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood.  Updated now to skip instead of printing.